# Transferring each column to one worksheet and then further from another sheet in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro which creates different worksheets on the basis of a data in column of first worksheet. This works absolutely fine as in Image 1.
[image]

So running the existing macro creates different sheets from 1st sheet called Scan.
Next I would like to create separate sheets in same way from sheet named STAFF in the same workbook using column E. 
[image]

The code I am using currently is

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vcol = 4
    Set ws = Sheets("Scan")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:F1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I would really appreciate any help with above.

Comment: You already have a code that works, so just go for the new range. What is the question?

Comment: Note that you use `On Error Resume Next` wrong. This line hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur. You just cannot see their messages. Remove this line and fix your errors or implement a proper error handling (VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)). Otherwise the result of your code is pretty much unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David and Peh, my question was how do I add additional code so that I can further create more sheets from the STAFF sheet column E same way as the sheet Scan. I can't figure this out as I am a novice.